# Call completion Handler function using "Result"

Tags: swift, closures

How to use call getEmployee function while using "Result"?

```
struct Employee {
    let name: String
    let designation: String
}

func getEmployee(name: String, completion: @escaping(Result<Employee?, Error>) -> Void) {

}
```

Comment: What is `Res` ? Did you mean `Result`?

Comment: This is for asynchronous requests

Comment: Yes, but how to get name from "Res","Employee" ?

Comment: You would need to first decode the data response from your API using usually JSONDecoder, then you call completion with the employee and the error

Comment: But how to see if Res has employee and error?

Comment: Added JSON to it as well for "Employee"

Comment: You need to return `.success(employee)` or `.failure(error)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make your structure conform to Codable

```
struct Employee: Codable {
    let name, designation: String
}
```

Than you need to fetch your data from your server and call completion if decoding was successful with your employee `.success(employee)` or if it fails pass failure with your error  `.failure(error)`:

---

```
func getEmployee(name: String, completion: @escaping(Result<Employee, Error>) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/getEmployee.api?name=\(name)")!) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)) }
            return
        }
        do {
            let employee = try JSONDecoder().decode(Employee.self, from: data)
            completion(.success(employee))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
getEmployee(name: "Ella") { result in
    switch result {
    case let .success(employee):
        print("employee:", employee)
    case let .failure(error):
        print("error:", error)
    default: break
    }
}
```