# Implement Decorator Pattern with generics in Swift

Tags: swift, design-patterns

I am new to Swift, but I have plenty of experience in other languages like Java, Kotlin, Javascript, etc. It's possible that what I want to do is not supported by the language, and I've poured over the [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide) looking for the answer.

I want to implement the decorator pattern, using generics. I easily did this in Kotlin, and I'm porting the library to Swift.

```swift
class Result<T> {
  let result: T?
  let error: NSError?

  init(result: T?, error: NSError?) {
    self.result = result
    self.error = error
  }
}

protocol DoSomething {
  associatedtype T

  func doSomething() -> Result<T>
}

protocol StoreSomething {
  associatedtype T

  func storeSomething(thing: Result<T>)
}

/*
 * DOES NOT COMPILE
 */
class StoringSomething<T> {
  private let delegate: DoSomething
  private let store: StoreSomething

  init(delegate: DoSomething, store: StoreSomething) {
    self.delegate = delegate
    self.store = store
  }

  func doSomething() -> Result<T> {
    let result = delegate.doSomething()

    store.storeSomething(thing: result)

    return result
  }
}
```

I get a `Protocol 'DoSomething' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` error from the compiler. I've tried using a `typealias` and other ideas from SO and the Swift manual.

Comment: A protocol it is requirement that a type must conform to. It is not a type. Think about FloatingPoint protocol. You never create an object setting its type to `FloatingPoint`. You set it to the types that conform to it like `Double`, `CGFloat`, `Float` etc...

Comment: Sure, and when I instantiated `StoringSomething` I would pass concrete implementations of the protocols. But I want the Decorator to wrap any type conforming the protocol/generic types

Comment: BTW `func doSomething() -> Result<T> {`
    `let result = delegate.doSomething()` doesn't make any sense you are creating a method and calling this method from itself

Comment: `func doSomething<T: YourProtocol>() -> Result<T> {`

Comment: Note that Swift already has a Result type.https://stackoverflow.com/a/62205976/2303865  This will overshadow it

Comment: @LeoDabus it's example code, because the project I'm working on is confidential. It encapsulates the problem however of using protocols with generics in a Decorator.

Comment: I think you need [type erasure](https://twittemb.github.io/swift/type%20erasure/protocol/generics/associatedtype/pattern/2017/11/09/type-erasure-in-swift/) here... (not to be confused with type erasure in Java) Make structs called `AnyDoSomething` and `AnyStoreSomething`.

Comment: @kierans Note that DoSomething  T has no relationship with StoreSomething T. You can't call store.storeSomething passing the result of delegate.doSomething. Btw there is no class or structure on your post that conform to those two protocols. What do you expect as a result type from your methods?

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper that was indeed it! :clap: :thumbs-up:

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Sweeper's [suggestion](https://twittemb.github.io/swift/type%20erasure/protocol/generics/associatedtype/pattern/2017/11/09/type-erasure-in-swift/) on `associatedtype` erasure you can implement the Decorator pattern with generics like so:

```swift
class AnyDoSomething<T>: DoSomething {
  func doSomething() -> Result<T> {
    fatalError("Must implement")
  }
}

class AnyStoreSomething<T>: StoreSomething {
  func storeSomething(thing: Result<T>) {
    fatalError("Must implement")
  }
}

class StoringSomething<T>: DoSomething {
  private let delegate: AnyDoSomething<T>
  private let store: AnyStoreSomething<T>

  init(delegate: AnyDoSomething<T>, store: AnyStoreSomething<T>) {
    self.delegate = delegate
    self.store = store
  }

  func doSomething() -> Result<T> {
    let result = delegate.doSomething()

    store.storeSomething(thing: result)

    return result
  }
}

class DoSomethingNice<T>: AnyDoSomething<T> {
  override func doSomething() -> Result<T> {

  }
}
```